# Классы и объекты в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Я хочу создать класс, но в отдельном файле и подключать уже к main файлу. Возникает 2 вопроса:

1) Как правильно реализовать класс в отдельном файле?

2) И как можно объявлять объекты класса, вне main функции?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создать файлы `A.h` и `A.cpp`.

```
//A.h
class A {
public:
    void foo();
};

//A.cpp
#include "A.h"
void A::foo() {
    //какие-то действия
}

//main.cpp
#include "A.h"

A myObj; //объявить глобальную переменную, если уж так хочется

int main() {
    myObj.foo();
}
```

Comment: чувствуется сессия близко :)